# Any android open source ImageView?

Tags: android, imageview

I need an ImageView that can be touched zoom in/out and pan. Each time when I touch the ImageView, I need to know the touch position of the source image. For example the image resolution is 1280*720, even the image in the ImageView is zoomed in, I still know exactly the touch position of the image(not touch position of the ImageView)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I used this open source code
https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom

I modified the code, but there is still a lot of bugs in this open source project, I have fixed several of them.

The following function was added to class ImageViewTouch.GestureListener which is used to transfer touchpoint(in screen) to point in the real image(no matter the image is zoom in/out).

```
    private PointF calculatePositionInSourceImage(PointF touchPointF) {
        //point relative to imageRect
        PointF touchPointRelativeToImageRect = new PointF();
        RectF imageRect = getBitmapRect();
        touchPointRelativeToImageRect.set(touchPointF.x - imageRect.left,
                touchPointF.y - imageRect.top);

        //real image resolution
        int imageWidth = getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
        int imageHeight = getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();

        //touch point in image
        PointF touchPointRelativeToImage = new PointF();
        touchPointRelativeToImage.set(touchPointRelativeToImageRect.x/imageRect.width() * imageWidth,
                touchPointRelativeToImageRect.y/imageRect.height() * imageHeight);

        if(touchPointRelativeToImage.x < 0 || touchPointRelativeToImage.y < 0 )
            touchPointRelativeToImage.set(0,0);

        return  touchPointRelativeToImage;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you skip all that and use an existing library?

Try this: [PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView)  works perfectly for me on API 23, with just a few lines of code you will be able to zoom in/out and pan

```
compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:1.3.0'

repositories {
    ...
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

Example

```
ImageView mImageView;
PhotoViewAttacher mAttacher;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

// Any implementation of ImageView can be used!
mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_photo);

// Set the Drawable displayed
Drawable bitmap = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.wallpaper);
mImageView.setImageDrawable(bitmap);

// Attach a PhotoViewAttacher, which takes care of all of the zooming functionality.
// (not needed unless you are going to change the drawable later)
mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(mImageView);
}

// If you later call mImageView.setImageDrawable/setImageBitmap/setImageResource/etc then you just need to call
mAttacher.update();
```

Comment: Seems good, May I get the touch position of the image in the ImageView/PhotoView?

Comment: PhotoView will take care of the zoom if you double tap the image will zoom on that position, if you need to know the position i think you can get those values from the library, but you will need to change a couple of things